# Is it bad form to intentionally trigger an excect block

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

Is there a better way of doing something like this:

```
class SpecialError(Exception):
    pass

try:
    # Some code that might fail
    a = float(a)
    # Some condition I want to check
    if a < 0:
        raise SpecialError
except (ValueError, SpecialError):
    # This code should be run if the code fails
    # or the condition is not met
    a = 999.
```

Comment: Nope, there are plenty of usecases where raising an exception is fine. I'd just raise `ValueError` in this case though, no need for a custom one.

Comment: Why not just check the condition before entering the block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explicitly raising exceptions is obviously useful in a wide range of use cases. But you're presumably talking about a narrow set of cases similar to yours, when you're raising an exception specifically to be caught within the local scope.

There's nothing wrong with that in general either. It may or may not be the most readable code, or the most communicative of your intentions, in any given use case, but that's really a style judgment more than anything else.

You can do this without the exception, at the cost of a minor DRY violation:

```
try:
    # Some code that might fail
    b = float(a)
    # Some condition I want to check
    if b < 0:
        b = 999.
except ValueError:
    # This code should be run if the code fails
    # or the condition is not met
    b = 999.
```

… or at the cost of slightly reordering your logic:

```
b = 999.
if a >= 0:
    try:
        b = float(a)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Alternatively, instead of creating a `SpecialError`, just use `ValueError`. Since it's not going to escape beyond this block, and your code treats them the same anyway, it's not adding anything:

```
try:
    b = float(a)
    if b < 0:
        raise ValueError
except ValueError:
    b = 999.
```

Use whichever of these you like best, and nobody will complain. If the one you like best doesn't involve a `raise`, then I guess the answer is, "Yes, there is a better way"; if it does, the answer is, "No, that's the best way." :)